# Open Implementation menu option in Eclipse with Camel Routes

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, ide, apache-camel

I've recently started using [Apache Camel](http://camel.apache.org/) in one of my Spring projects. One of the annoyances with this framework has been the inability to use Spring Tool Suite / Eclipse's click through menu to jump straight from my Camel route to the method being called via a `.beanRef('bean', 'method')` code. I understand that it doesn't popup the option in Eclipse because the beanRef is using String's to determine what to call, but I was looking online for something that would allow that functionality specifically for Camel projects.

Does anyone know of an Eclipse (or STS) plugin that will allow me to Cmd+Click or Ctrl+Click into a method from the Camel route when I'm doing research or performing a code review for another member on the team?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is Fuse IDE which is a Camel editor for Eclipse: http://fusesource.com/products/fuse-ide/

Though I don't think we have added support for clicking on a beanRef, method, and other Camel tags which can refer to spring beans. Its a good idea, so I have logged a ticket: http://fusesource.com/issues/browse/ECLIPSE-950 about this idea.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I did try out the Fuse IDE while researching this, so I will definitely keep an eye on the ticket.